# Change the url in the address bar

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have two modules..tempalate and youraccount

In my template module has a view file named customer_panel
This is the contents of the file customer_panel.php

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?> youraccount/logout "class =" ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-action ui-btn-b "> Logout </a>
```

Then on module youraccount I have a controller youraccount.php
In which there is a function

```
Function logout()
{
     Unset($ _ SESSION ['user_id']);
     $ This->load->module('site_cookies');
     $ This->site_cookies->_destroy_cookie ();

     redirect(base_url());
}
```

My base_url address is localhost/mywebsite

When I clicked the logout button it was indeed pointing to my home page
And the link in the address bar is localhost/mywebsite/youraccount/logout

Can my address bar go to localhost/mywebsite when I click the logout button ..?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not post the code of the function `redirect()` I can not specifically answer to that function.

> `redirect(base_url());`

My suggestion would be to replace the custom `redirect()` function and use the php `header()` function instead:

```
header('Location: ' . base_url());
```

---

**Update**
Before you can use the `redirect()` command in CodeIgniter you need to load the [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) module:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect(base_url());
```

If that doesn't help, you could try to change the [redirection method](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect).
Try both of them:

```
redirect(base_url(), 'location');
// or
redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
```

Comment: I tried to use it but still can not work.
I will try to find more references about header ()

Comment: `header()` does work only if there was no output before.

Comment: Are you using a php framework or have you written the code by yourself? If it's not a framework, could you, please, paste the code of the  `redirect()` function.

Comment: I use codeigniter framework ..
I'm building its mobile version .. using jQuery Mobile
When I open on the website it runs fine .. his direct link leads to localhost / mywebsite as I want
But if it opens using mobile browser, its page is pointing to localhost / mywebsite where it is home from my website .. but address in the address bar does not change, keep localhost / mywebsite / youraccount / logout

Comment: $http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$newurl = str_replace("index.php","", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $newurl;

Comment: It is my config.php

Comment: I've added an update to my answer above. Does it help?

Comment: I have tried what you suggest..but nothing has been done yet